# if A1 = 1 then cell value =A1, if it is 2 then i wanted the formula to change to A2,

Tags: excel

I need some help here with my work.
I am doing pure formulas in excel and won't be using anything else.

sorry to confuse u guys, maybe I'll change my question a tad more clearer to what I need.

I wanted to increment my cell references in the formula every time a day is added.

let's say today was Feb 1, 2014. I'd set A1 = 1, now when I enter Feb 2, 2014 on my date entry cell. A1 should change to 2.

I need the proper formula for this statement as follows, If A1 = 1, then B2 = H2, B3 = H3, now when A2 changes to 2 after the date change, my formula should become B2 = H3, B3 = H4, I can't get this part.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Could you show the `IF` statement in the formula context?

Comment: hey @MarkFitzgerald thank you for your time on my question. I have edited it, see if it is more detailed now?

Comment: I just made a change to my answer for clarity. It seems you had already worked it out from my earlier brief answer though! Thanks for the tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if A1 = 1 then cell value =A1, if it is 2 then i wanted the formula to change to A2
>
> if today's date is the 1st day then my cell value in A1 = 1

What you want is slightly confusing if I consider the above two statements. Is this what you want?

```
=INDIRECT("A" & DAY(TODAY()))
```

This will give you `A12's` value for `12th Jan 2014 (Since it is the 12th day)`

**Followup from comments.**

> Let's say i take my data to be displayed in A3 from B3, my formula will be A3 = B3 in simple terms, but the next day I will need A3 to take data from B4 instead as B3 will be my past data already, how will I increment the formula to change to A3 = B4?

So my understanding was correct :) Ok Let's say your current formula in `A3` is `=B3` and you are storing the date say in cell `D1` then change the formula in cell `A3` to

```
=INDIRECT("B" & DAY(D1))
```

So if you input say `04/01/2014 (i.e 4th Jan 2014)` in cell `D1` then the cell `A3` formula evaluates to

```
=INDIRECT("B" & DAY(D1))
=INDIRECT("B" & DAY(04/01/2014))
=INDIRECT("B" & 4)
=INDIRECT("B4") '<~~~
```

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: Wouldn't `DAY(TODAY())` give `1` for 1st of feb too?

Comment: It is unclear if the OP wants the formula to reset at the beginning of each month, or if the formula should just continue to increment.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: Honestly, I am kind of confused as to what OP wants. I just answered the question best to my understanding. If my understanding is incorrect then I will delete the answer :)

Comment: @Boss.Marv: `A1 should change to 2` for this put the formula `=Day(Date Cell)` in A1. This will automatically change the value of A1

Comment: I still can't get it right, I just needed my formula cell references to change every time i update the excel. Let's say i take my data to be displayed in A3 from B3, my formula will be A3 = B3 in simple terms, but the next day I will need A3 to take data from B4 instead as B3 will be my past data already, how will I increment the formula to change to A3 = B4? Forgive me on my ignorance.

Comment: @Boss.Marv: see the updated post `Followup from comments`. you may have to refresh the page.

Comment: @SiddharthRout omg thanks for your help, I got what I wanted! ok so how do I bring up your rep

Comment: @Boss.Marv: Glad it worked for you :) You have already accepted the answer and that is good enough. However to answer your query, to increase a user's rep you can do two things. `1` Accept the answer `2` Vote up. You can only vote answers if you have certain reputation level. You may want to read [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: What if the data I need increments by column and not by row? How do I do that in the formula?

Comment: @Boss.Marv: I see you have unaccepted my answer. Was some info missing especially when I accurately answered your original question?

Comment: @SiddharthRout the question was answered perfectly fine, just had another problem came up, the other formula needed to be incremented by column

Comment: @Boss.Marv: If you have separate question then it is always advisable to ask a separate question and not juggle between answers by new requirements. I am ok if you still go ahead with Mark's answer but then please stick to it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Define a named range** such as `DateEntryCell` for the cell where you enter the date. In `A1` you need a formula to return the day of the date entered in your `DateEntryCell` range.

```
=DAY(DateEntryCell)
```

In 'B2' enter

```
=INDIRECT("H" & $A$1 + ROW()-1)
```

The absolute reference to `$A$1` means you can copy this formula down to `B3`. Adding `ROW()-1` incorporates your offset between row 1 where you have `=DAY(DateEntryCell)` and `B2`, `B3` etc.